# Is it possible to use app with CloudKit without creating new container but use an existing?

Tags: ios, cloudkit

When I turn on CloudKit capability, it automatically creates a container. Sometimes it is frustrating, because I want to use an other instead of the default. Any idea how?

---

What disturbes me, that now I have planty of containers already in Dashboard, and hard to navigate / scroll among them. So I don not want to create more unused. But first when I turn on capability, it automatically creates the default container, even though in next turn I select an other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have to change the bundle ID in before set specific container. Set bundle ID so that the default container will choosen according the the name, so if it already exist, then Xcode will not create new container. Then turn on CloudKit, then change back bundle ID. That is all.

Answer (score 1):

1. As Edwin suggests, you need to specify the containers your app should have access to in the Capabilities pane of Xcode. You'll want to select "Specify custom containers" and choose the appropriate ones:
   [image: Xcode]
2. You need to access those containers in your code using their identifier, like so:

`let container1 = CKContainer(identifier: "iCloud.com.MyCompany.Container1")`

`let container2 = CKContainer(identifier: "iCloud.com.MyCompany.Container2")`

Answer (score 0):

Default container names are based on your bundle identifier. You can specify that you want a different container. See the CloudKit settings of your target. Just click the 'specify custom container'

Comment: I must say I tried this and it did not completely work. I did not have a chance to understand why. If this works for someone please let us know.

Comment: so u edit bundle identifier first, to the appropriate one, selectect other container, and then reverse the bundle identifier?